# Get exact browser rendered text (RTL and LTR direction mix)

Tags: javascript, html, right-to-left, bidi

Is there a way to retrieve the actual rendered text by a browser (in the context of Right-to-left text direction)?

```
<html dir="rtl">
<body>
  <p id='ko'>Hello (world)</p>
  <p id='ok'>Hello <bdo dir='ltr'>(world)</bdo></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Will render :

- in chrome

[image]

- in firefox

[image]

But both
`document.getElementById('ok').textContent === document.getElementById('ko').textContent`
and 
`document.getElementById('ok').innerText === document.getElementById('ko').innerText` are `true` (for both browsers).

Is there a way to get the actual text that is displayed in the webpage?

https://jsfiddle.net/019kvo56/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `direction` CSS property that you can grab from e.g `getComputedStyle(elem)`, but this is only at the element level, so you can't know exactly how the browser did render the textNodes.

So what you need to do is :

- first grab all the textNodes from your container (best done with a [TreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker)).
- select each of its characters with an [Range object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)
- get each character's current position thanks to the Range's [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) method.
- sort them
- get back their text values

Here is a live demo :

```js
function getDisplayedText(container) {

  var r = document.createRange(); // to get our nodes positions

  var nodes = []; // first grab all the nodes
  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(container, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);
  while (treeWalker.nextNode()) nodes.push(treeWalker.currentNode);

  var chars = []; // then get all its contained characters
  nodes.forEach(n => {
    n.data.split('').forEach((c, i) => {
      r.setStart(n, i); // move the range to this character
      r.setEnd(n, i+1);
      chars.push({
        text: c,
        rect: r.getBoundingClientRect() // save our range's DOMRect
      })
    })
  });

  return chars.filter(c => c.rect.height) // keep only the displayed ones (i.e no script textContent)
    .sort((a, b) => { // sort ttb ltr
      if (a.rect.top === b.rect.top) {
        return a.rect.left - b.rect.left;
      }
      return a.rect.top - b.rect.top;
    })
    .map(n => n.text)
    .join('');
}

console.log('ko : ', getDisplayedText(ko));
console.log('ok : ', getDisplayedText(ok));
```

```html
<div dir="rtl">
  <p id='ko'>Hello (world)</p>
  <p id='ok'>Hello <bdo dir='ltr'>(world)</bdo></p>
</div>
```

And now, as to why webkit does render the last `)` flipped and first... I've got no idea if they're correct or not to do so...