# How to get specific character data from text in canvas ? (important in MultiDir: RTL / LTR String)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, typography

I have multi-dir text and i want mark Or select some charachter (for sample last char)
Sample string : **"معنی Hello سلام است یا Salam"**
Some chars extent the text from Left and some chars extent it from Right.(you can copy text in editor and use BackSpace to Delete chars one By one to see better)
I want to see Where is "H" character position in this Canvas Or which character clicked by user ... ?

`canvas.measureText(txt.slice(0,dest)).width`  Not work. Becouse i Dont know my chars are Growing from right or left?

i check canvas text functions , and google it and SEE NOTHING!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Canvas2D API still lacks a proper API to handle text correctly. In all fairness, it's been years people have been working on various things, but text is *very* complicated.

So for the time being, there is nothing that will give you this per glyph level of information, `measureText()` only takes a bunch of text and doesn't expose each glyph.

What you can do, if you have access to a CSS renderer (e.g because your script is running in a browser), is to use CSS to render your text, and then use the DOM `Range` API, which kind of exposes enough info to at least get a per character bounding box (with less details than the canvas `TextMetrics`, but which should be enough for your case).

and here is a monster, which takes off some code from a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695297/get-exact-browser-rendered-text-rtl-and-ltr-direction-mix/44699154#44699154) on a non-canvas-centered question. Note that this isn't pixel perfect, and that it mixes characters and glyphs, which *is* a problem, most notably with Arabic scripts.

```js
const text = "معنی Hello سلام است یا Salam";
const x = 10;
const y = 50;
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px sans-serif";
ctx.textBaseLine = "alphabetic";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";

// See below for the helper functions
// Get the list of all chars and their BBox, sorted rtl-ttb
const chars = getDisplayedChars(text, ctx.font);
// Get the BBox of the whole text (fails in Firefox with this text...)
const wholeMetrics = getCanvasTextBox(ctx, text);
// Compute the relative boxes, in canvas.
const relativeChars = chars.map(({ text, rect }) => {
  const left = rect.left + wholeMetrics.left + x;
  const top = rect.top + wholeMetrics.top + y;
  return new DOMRect(left, top, rect.width, rect.height);
});

let hovered = null;
draw();

canvas.onmousemove = ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
  const { left, top } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = clientX - left;
  const y = clientY - top;
  const lastHovered = hovered;
  hovered = findCharAt(x, y);  
  if (lastHovered !== hovered) {
    draw();
  }
};
function findCharAt(x, y) {
  return relativeChars.find(({ top, right, bottom, left }) => {
    return left <= x && right >= x &&
      top <= y && bottom >= y;
  });
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
  if (hovered) {
    ctx.strokeRect(hovered.left, hovered.top, hovered.width, hovered.height);
  }
}

function getDisplayedChars(text, fontStyle) {
  // Won't work in StackSnippet, but using an iframe allows to not be polluted by CSS
  const frame = document.createElement("iframe");
  document.body.append(frame);
  const doc = frame.contentDocument || document;
  const container = doc.createElement("div");
  container.style.font = fontStyle;
  container.textContent = text;
  doc.body.prepend(container);
  const range = doc.createRange(); // to get our nodes positions
  
  // First we get the full text BBox, so we can later have relative positions
  range.selectNode(container);
  const mainBBox = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  const chars = [];
  const node = container.firstChild;
  node.data.split("").forEach((char, index) => {
    range.setStart(node, index); // Move the range to this character
    range.setEnd(node, index + 1);
    const nodeBBox = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rect = getRelativeBBox(mainBBox, nodeBBox);
    chars.push({ char, rect });
  });

  container.remove();
  frame.remove();
  
  return chars.filter((char) => char.rect.height) // Keep only the displayed ones
    .sort((a, b) => { // Sort ttb-ltr
      return a.rect.top - b.rect.top ||
        a.rect.left - b.rect.left;
    })
}
function getRelativeBBox(from, to) {
  const x = to.left - from.left;
  const y = to.top - from.top;
  return new DOMRect(x, y, to.width, to.height);
}
// Returns a BBox based on a TextMetrics
// relative to {0,0}
function getCanvasTextBox(ctx, text) {
  const metrics = ctx.measureText(text);
  const left    = metrics.actualBoundingBoxLeft * -1;
  const top     = metrics.actualBoundingBoxAscent * -1;
  const right   = metrics.actualBoundingBoxRight;
  const bottom  = metrics.actualBoundingBoxDescent;
  const width   = right - left;
  const height  = bottom - top;
  return new DOMRect(left, top, width, height);
}
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=80></canvas><br>
Hover over each character to show its bounding-box.
```